# Is voting up a duplicate comment the same thing as marking it as a duplicate?

Tags: support, comments, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

I have noticed now that when you mark a question as a duplicate, a comment is automatically added in the nature of:

> Possible Duplicate [Question Title of Duplicate Goes Here]

I have also noticed that if you go through the flag menu and mark the question as duplicate of the same question the other person marked it as a duplicate as, it will automatically up vote their comment.

If I up vote a "possible duplicate ..." comment, is that the same thing as going through the flag menu and marking it as a duplicate?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

No; the fact that the duplicate comment is upvoted is independent of the flag/vote to close of a duplicate.

As you've observed, if you flag or vote to close a question as a duplicate of another, if someone else has the specific link to that specific duplicate, their comment is upvoted.  This includes comments that just link to a possible duplicate but have not flagged or voted to close the question.

Conversely, if you simply upvote the comment, that only impacts the comment, which is independent of the flag.

Comment: _"if you flag or vote to close a question as a duplicate of another, if someone else has the specific link to that specific duplicate, their comment is upvoted"_ Huh, didn't know that.

Comment: I've seen comments like this upvoted 8-10 times while the question remains open!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:  As an added bonus, if the question is successfully closed, the comment with the link is deleted - even if it isn't the "possible duplicate of"-type comment.

Comment: @Makoto: Well I knew that bit - have accidentally nuked comments that way :P

Comment: @Makoto I've had comments of mine nuked that way, I was quite confused at first.

Answer (score 8):

NO.

Upvoting a comment does nothing other than upvote the comment.

To vote/flag to close as dup, you need to use the normal flag/close vote process.