# Is there any reason to select a "delete reason" comment if it has already been added to a post?

Tags: discussion

When reviewing Low Quality Posts, I often see that someone else has already voted to delete and added one of the available list of comments from the "Recommend Deletion" dialog to the post. In many cases, I agree with the comment and would choose the same one, but I was wondering: is there any point to it if the comment is already there?

Mostly I'm just not sure if my choosing one of the options actually does anything behind the scenes besides add the comment. I don't want to just lazily click the delete button with "no comment needed" selected if it's going to go down on my permanent record, but if it isn't, then I do.

Comment: AFAIK, if you choose the same, it just upvotes the comment that's already there

Comment: @Patrice:  [Yes, that's right.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/312271/1079354)

Comment: @Makoto It's [supposed to work that way](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265249/preventing-multiple-of-the-same-low-quality-review-comments/265272#comment59331_265249), but it's [not clear if it does](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265249/preventing-multiple-of-the-same-low-quality-review-comments) (no status tag)..

Comment: That was a recent change (I believe it happened at the same time that we got the "From Review" link added to comments). It used to add duplicate comments, then directly after the change it would just not add duplicate comments (but it didn't upvote the comment either). I have only been in the CVQ for the last while so I don't know what the current functionality is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only time I've selected a delete reason is:

- If I feel that the point should be emphasized
- If I feel that a different reason is necessary
- If there are no reasons otherwise, and simply deleting it wouldn't indicate the error of one's ways

If you don't feel that you need to comment, then no one is forcing you to do so.  If what you wanted to say was already expressed, then there's no reason to feel like you need to express it again to appease anyone.